# Issue came up in resolving ModuleNotFoundError with file not found after package conflicts found

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, nosuchfileexception

I am trying to launch Spyder from anaconda navigator on my machine with Python 3.9, Anaconda 3, and MacOS M1 Monterey 12.1 (Just in case this might be a machine error I'm not aware about). I posted earlier trying to resolve an error that occurred when I tried to launch Spyder:  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'` 
When I tried to pip install the module, I got another error saying `metadata-generation-failed`. A user gave me a solution: running `conda install -c anaconda pyqt` and then `conda install -c conda-forge pyqtwebengine`. When I ran the former line, it went through with no issue but when I ran the latter, the terminal said there were many package conflicts and when I tried to run Spyder, it returns

```
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3: /Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No such file or directory
```

How would I resolve this new issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe running something like the following could help: `conda install -f python.app` (following the comment https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9951#issuecomment-517913824 at an issue with a similar traceback https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9951)

Comment: @Daniel Althviz: Hi Daniel! I looked at that and ran that line in terminal as well, but it did not resolve the issue, unfortunately. Spyder returns that same error and just now, it returned the modulenotfound error for pyqt5webengine again.

Comment: Could you try to create a new env using the conda-forge channel? For that you should run from a terminal something like `conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge python=3.9 spyder=5.3.0`